# Unable to remove content-type header angular8

Tags: angular

I am new to angular 8 and i am trying to post file with some json data to rest service. Since my service wont accept multipart form data request if there is content-type header available in request headers. I tried to delete header, but to my surprise i see content-type header and value in request headers.

My code

```
addProd(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.delete("content-type");
//delete headers['content-type'];
//headers.set('content-type',undefined);
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', apiUrl + "product", formData,{
  headers:headers
});
return this.http.request(req).pipe(
  tap(_ => this.log("added product")),
  catchError(this.handleError("add product"))
);}
```

My form data

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', this.fileData, this.fileData.name);
formData.append('product', JSON.stringify(productData));
```

request headers from mozilla browser

[image: request headers]

I tried setting value as `undefined` but i am getting exception in console `values are undefined`.

Can anyone help me how can i post data without content-type header in request.

Comment: Probably angular inserts the headers a little bit later. Try to remove it in an interceptor.

Comment: Thanks @jpavel for your reply but I dont know how to add an interceptor can u help me on this

Comment: I'll try to elaborate an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the desired header (if possible - some headers are just impossible to remove) in an interceptor.

#### 1 - Build a service that implements the `HttpInterceptor` interface

```js
@Injectable()
export class RemoveHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    // Get the headers without content-type
    const {'content-type', others } = req.headers;

    // As the request is immutable, clone the original
    // with the new headers
    const newReq = req.clone({
      headers: others
    });

    // dispatch the new request with the new headers
    // without content-type
    return next.handle(newReq);
  }
}
```

#### 2 - After doing that, you need to provide the service with a special token (`HTTP_INTERCEPTORS`) on your root module (likely `AppModule`):

```js
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    { 
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
      useClass: RemoveHeaderInterceptor, 
      multi: true 
    },
    ...
  ],
  ..
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks @jpavel for you help. I just figured out that my application has already other interceptor which is appending content-type by default. I just updated that according to my needs. Thanks to you that iam able to debug quickly ( idea of interceptor)